# How to prove $a = b$ implies $ca = cb$ and $ac = bc$

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group and also let $a, b, c \in G$.

How to prove $a = b$ implies $ca = cb$? Simillary, how $a = b$ implies $ac = bc$?

Is this considered to be obvious because an object $a$ is same as object $b$ or there is some weird proof with equivalence relations or something for this? (Just checking.).Thanks.

Comment: cancel $c$ on both sides

Comment: @Mather Rather multiply with $c$ on both sides.

Comment: The map $\cdot :G\times G\to G$ is a function, so you are just evaluating it in the same pair $(c,a)=(c,b)$.

Comment: the operation $\cdot$ is a function. So it's obvious that if $a = b$, then $\cdot (c, a) = \cdot (c, b)$

Comment: @quantumspace yeah, we can also do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the multiplication map $m: G \times G \to G$. Then
$$ca = m(c,a) = m(c,b) = cb.$$

Imlicitly, it is used that $m$ is a function (as opposed to a relation).

Comment: Yes, $a = b$ so we are plotting in the same object and then, of course, getting the same output. Thanks.

Comment: @Learner Yes indeed. Btw, you are right to stand still with these seemingly obvious statements. It is important to realise early on in your math education what is going on :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Learner You are welcome. Good luck!